# SSRS report server unable to see updates to stored procedure immediately.....How to change this?

Tags: stored-procedures, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am constantly making stored procedures and then using these stored procedures within SSRS reports.  It is fairly common for my SSRS report to be unable to find my stored procedures.  So, I sit there and delete the datasource, refresh it, over and over until it is able to find my new stored procedure.

**Update:  The error is this: Could not find stored procedure 'NAME OF SP'(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2812)

This is annoying, I feel as if there is some table that SSRS uses or needs updated so that I can instantly see newly created stored procedures.

I currently made a change to a live stored procedure and my live SSRS report is not taking these changes yet and it is several hours later.

I know that there has to be some process or table that is not updated on our system instantly.

Just wondering if anyone knows of a system job or table to reference to make this update either more frequently or something I can run manually when I need it.

Any thoughts/advice is greatly appreciated....Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, very poor workaround, but this is what I have found.  If it continues to give you this error, you can just go into the drop down box and find your stored procedure in the list.  Click it, run it, then click refresh and this error should go away.  If you can't find it in the list then you have a bigger issue.